# How to display Firebase Parents in Listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The first 2 keys dont have child but others have them. I'm able to display the child elements when there is only one parent and I can display Admin/User details using data object model but how to display parent elements(Bright Kid Test & others) in Listview?

This is an image of Firebase Database:

[image: This is an image of Firebase Database]

Code:

```
   listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.preschool_list);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Preschools");

    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            list.add(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

If there is only one child of preschools then it is displayed else no value is shown.

Comment: Is getChildren() applicable for datasnapshot? I'm not getting how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer with datasnapshot.getChildren().

```
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                list.add(String.valueOf(dsp.getKey()));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to display text Bright Kid LL, Bright Kid Mont, Bright Kid Test in list view, don't you? You can get them by `getKey()`

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot recipeSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String key = recipeSnapshot.getKey();
                list.add(key);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```